# How to avoid loading initially hidden tableviews in .nib files?

Tags: ios, xcode, lazy-loading, tableview, nib

In my applications I have nibs which include up to 3 tableviews each, one above the other, which I set to hidden whenever their corresponding tab (i.e. segmented control segment) is not selected.

The question is: can I avoid loading all the nib components if they are not needed (i.e. hidden)? Let's say I have 3 tables in a view and I want to load just the first one (the one above), loading the other tableviews on demand if needed. Is constructing the tableview programmatically the only way to achieve this?

Just for clarification: I am not using the same tableview with different data sources because I want to manage the "drag to refresh view" on each table separately and I like the idea to have separate tables (it seems more neat to me).

Answer (score 0):

Just divide that NIB in 3 nibs with a UITableViewController each and switch them programmatically on-demand. Your code will be more organized and your resources easier to maintain. Simplify!